# View local website on an Android device

Tags: usb, browser, reverse-tether

Web developer here.

I have two devices, a Samsung Galaxy S3 & a Samsung Note 10.1. I have developed a website which is running on PHP and I would like to view my website on these two devices without having to upload it to an online server. My local server is a WAMPSERVER.

I've heard that you could use Wi-Fi and connect to my PC's IP address however my wifi signal is very weak (I use a desktop upstairs, router is downstairs) so I would like a setup that requires me to physically connect my devices to my PC through a USB cable. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: That's called [reverse-tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether). I took the freedom to attach the tag to your question. You can follow this link to see other questions (with answers) discussing this, and extract a solution fitting your situation. So much in advance: reverse-tether usually requires root access to the device. But AFAIK there are also USB-Ethernet adapters (I've just heard about, but have no experience with those).

Comment: Thank you @Izzy! I feel i'm on the right path to something. 

I've tried typing in my PC's IP address however I get "**Forbidden** You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: I don't know where you're "typing in" the address, so I cannot follow. But have you checked the link from my previous comment? Anything matching? Any success? My recommendation is starting with those, and then reporting back by either answering your own question (if you succeeded), or [edit] it with what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @Izzy, I'm getting internet from my PC to my phone so I know theres a connection happening. 

Now, I want to be able to view my website on my phone. I've tried typing my PC's IPv4 address into my phone's web browser and the message I receive is "**Forbidden** You don't have permission to access / on this server". I tried typing the wampserver's IP address and I get no luck from that.

Comment: Ah! Now that get's clearer. Guess that part is rather an issue for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Check your web server's logs for why it's rejecting you. Maybe it only accepts connections from localhost, or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much help this is, but I've had success using the reverse tethering solution with IIS, so it must have something to do with your server. With IIS I connect using the Ip 192.168.0.0:port/{path of directory within IIS instance}

Hope this helps